# How to deduce properties of ProductLog?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How to simplify the following expression

```
ProductLog[Log[x^x]]//PowerExpand[#,Assumptions->And[x\[Element]Reals,Log[x^x]>=1/E]]&
```

How do I show `ProductLog[Log[x^x]]==Log[x]`?

Comment: What is your problem ?  Since `FullSimplify[ProductLog[Log[x^x]] == Log[x], x > 1/E]` yields `True`?

Comment: @Artes sorry was putting the constraint wrong. It was `x>=1/E` and not `Log[x^x]>=1/E`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try executing

```
Solve[x^x == z, x]
```

then replace z with x^x and solve for Productlog.

You can also do

```
FullSimplify[ProductLog[x Log[x]], x >= 1/E]
```